# Filter lines by categ_id and count qty

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

My goal is to loop through all lines with the same categ_id and calculate total quantity they have and `if qty_categ_total < categ_id.qty_for_discount` ( I added this field to 'product.category' than I need to post a message in text fields. the problem my code is not working as I want.

Example.

If I have 2 lines with the same `categ_id` with qty 2 and 5 and my `categ_id.qty_for_discount` is 10. The message should say that I need to add 3 more products with the same `categ_id` to get discount

**Update**

And if there are products with different categories I should get a message for each category

```py
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order'

    discount_warning_message = fields.Text(string='Discount Warning', compute='discount_warning')

     @api.depends('order_line.product_id', 'order_line.product_qty')
def discount_warning(self):
    qty_categ_total = 0.0
    for line in self.order_line:
        qty_categ_total +=  line.product_qty
        if qty_categ_total < line.product_id.categ_id.qty_for_discount:
            message = (_("You can get discount if you add %s more %s\n")) % (qty_categ_total, line.product_id.categ_id.name)
            self.discount_warning_message = message
```

Comment: What is your current result?

Comment: Probably not your only problem but : -#1 the assignment to self.discount_warning_message should be out of the loop. -#2 you're not bothering to check the categ_id, despite mentionning them as relevant.

Comment: @T.Nel yes both your points are very correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct, but i would change something. First either use `@api.one` to let odoo automatically loop through all orders or add one more for each loop and `@api.multi`. And secondly what about more than one category?

```py
@api.multi
@api.depends('order_line.product_id', 'order_line.product_qty')
def discount_warning(self):
    msg = _("You can get discount if you add %s more %s\n")
    for order in self:
        categ_qtys = {}
        for line in order.order_line:
            if line.product_id.categ_id not in categ_qtys:
                categ_qtys[line.product_id.categ_id] = 0.0
            categ_qtys[line.product_id.categ_id] += line.product_qty
        msgs = []
        for categ, qty in categ_qtys.iteritems():
            if qty < categ.qty_for_discount:
                msgs.append(msg % (qty, categ.name))
        if msgs:
            order.discount_warning_message = "".join(msgs)
```

General advice: Always try to debug into your methods. Are they even called? If not, the methods aren't the problem.

Comment: yes i debugged it , method works. if there is more than one category i probably should get 2 messages for each category.

Comment: I mean message for each category. I updated my question.

Comment: @Chaban33 You should already have one message line per category with this answer. msgs is a list of messages. One message is added per category (if at least one order of the category and not enought quantity for discount), then all the messages are joined in discount_warning_message

Comment: I'm sorry it was my testing mistake.

Comment: The debugging thing at the end of my answer was just a general advice, edited it.